# Is there a way to install the MS Windows version of msn?

Tags: msn

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)

I need to install Msn - the Windows version of MSN, but can only find Amsn which is not what I need.

Is there a way to install Windows's Msn?

Comment: @dobey im ask for msn not general "windows software or games" ... u not know all software not have same compatibiliti?

Comment: It's software designed for Windows and you're trying to run it on Ubuntu. Of course it's not compatible. However, the process is the same for installing it, whether or not it actually works. Even if you do get it installed and running, there is no guarantee that everything will work as it would on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made your question clearer. Next time look up a bilingual dictionary in your language :) You'll learn to ask better questions.

So, as I understood you don't want Amsn and the likes.. Then you say that you want to install msn ("the Windows one") instead.

If you're so keen on wanting to use that and aren't interested in Amsn's msn like themes and plugins, to make yourself feel more familiar, then it's possible to go straight installing msn.

In your terminal (or 'command line') write this text and hit enter:

```
apt-get install wine*
```

After it's done you can download msn from the official site (not sure about that) and install it as you would in Windows.

Let me know if this helped you. I'll update this question if necessary.

Comment: this answer needs expanding - if you visit winehq you'll see that several versions are marked as "garbage" which means they do not work. http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=127

Comment: @fossfreedom 7.0 .. for me is good .. am not need new version just this good enough

Comment: that's ok - you've picked the silver rated version.